# Check if scope is called on class or instance (scoped)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a scope:

```
class Post
  belongs_to: :user
  scope(:visible_for, ->(user = default_user) { where("<some SQL>") })
end
```

Is there a way to check inside the scope whether it has been called 1. scoped or 2. unscoped?

1. `some_user.posts.visible_for`
2. `Post.visible_for`

Reason I want this is scoped automatically includes `WHERE posts.user_id = <user_id>` which optimizes the query, and I want only optimized query to be legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found you can call `scope_attributes` inside the scope, problem solved.